# Graph MySQL data on index.php page: How to import MySQL column data as (x,y)-coordinates in jpgraph?

Tags: php, mysql, graphing, jpgraph

Got a database called `db`. Got a table called `table`. `table`'s got two columns of interest called `num` and `date`.

What I want to do, using [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#line1), is "import" `num` and `date`'s values as arrays using `mysqli_fetch_array` (or something else) to assign each respectively to their corresponding x and y arrays for the jpgraph functionality.

---

If you know of a better way to import MySQL column data into a historic line plot within a PHP page, using another way, I would like to know as jpgraph seems a bit outdated...

---

```
<!-- DATABASE STUFF HERE -->

<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');

$query = "SELECT num FROM table ORDER BY blah";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    <!-- PUT INTO ARRAY CALLED $data_num -->
}
$datay = $data_num;
.
.
.
<!-- BUNCH OF JPGRAPH CODE YOU DON'T NEED TO SEE -->
?>
```

---

Actually, there seems to be quite the marketplace for PHP graphing, like [PHPGraph](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/examples). What they all rely on is importing your array. What I really need to know is how to import an array in PHP from my database (MySQL) and assign it as an array that PHPGraph can handle (or some other program). I had some problems with the code above (see below for snippet):

```
$query = "SELECT num FROM table ORDER BY blah";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    <!-- PUT INTO ARRAY CALLED $data_num -->
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to pin down what you're asking here. Are you asking about how to use JPGraph in particular? I expect you'd do a `SELECT` over the rows you are interested in, and then supply an array of data to the graphing library in the format it requires? There are [several examples](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto1.php) in the docs.

Comment: I haven't encountered this library before, but the last release date noted on its website is October 2010, so you may wish to choose another library. Are you particularly looking for a library that creates images, as I assume this one does? Most web-based solutions now are JavaScript, SVG and/or Canvas these days, I'd guess.

Comment: @halfer, how could you make a graph in JavaScript?

Comment: I remember liking [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) when it was a thing, though that too is old now. Do a search on GitHub, there are bound to be loads of others.

Comment: Actually, `chart.js` looks promising.

Comment: Yes, images of graphs made dynamically from MySQL data via PHP, but the display platform needn't be PHP.